# Looping through a sum to control layout in PHP, adds extra div at the end

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I have a block of PHP code that iterates through an array called `entriesConverted[]` and calculates the `sum` of the columns as it goes. When the `sum` equals `1` it closes the `.row` and starts another.

This works fine apart from when it's the last column/row that equals `1` it creates a blank `.row` div as it's matching the statement. So, I understand why it's doing this, but what I'm not sure on it how to fix it so that if there's no more entries in the array, it doesn't create another `.row` div.

My `entriesConverted[]` array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [content] => "<h1>Page main heading here</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>"
            [column_size] => 1
            [text_align] => Center
            [raw_html] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [content] => "<h3>Test entry</h3>"
            [column_size] => 0.5
            [text_align] => Center
            [raw_html] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [content] => "<h3>Test entry2</h3><p>Bit of text underneath to see what happens</p>"
            [column_size] => 0.5
            [text_align] => Center
            [raw_html] => 0
        )
)
```

And my PHP block that runs through it (uses the `column_size` to determine what should be calculated together):

```
<?php
$entriesConverted = [];

// Set the sum to 0 to keep things clean and simple
$sum = 0;

// Echo the starting div
echo '<div class="content-block homepage-block row">';

// Loop through the new columns
foreach($entriesConverted as $newEntry){
    for ($i=$newEntry['column_size']; $i <= 1; $i++) {
        $sum += $i;
        $newEntry['column_size'] = str_replace([0.25, 0.33, 0.5, 0.67, 0.75, 1], ['col-md-3', 'col-md-4', 'col-md-6', 'col-md-8', 'col-md-9', 'col-md-12'], $newEntry['column_size']);
        $newEntry['text_align'] = str_replace(['Left', 'Center', 'Right', 'Justified'], ['text-left', 'text-center', 'text-right', 'text-justify'], $newEntry['text_align']);
        echo '<div class="'.$newEntry['column_size'].' '.$newEntry['text_align'].'">';
            echo $newEntry['content'];
        echo '</div>';
    }
    if($sum == 1){
        $sum = 0;
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="content-block homepage-block row">';
    }
}
// Echo closing div
echo '</div>';
?>
```

An example output from above is this:

[image]

As you can see from the screen shot it creates the first row and the `col-md-12` which is equal to the `1` in the `column_size` and then for the next 2 array objects it creates a row and places 2 `col-md-6` (which is referring the 2 `0.5` column sizes) inside which is fine, however, you can see the highlighted extra div caused by my `if` statement.

I've spent a few hours on this trying different ideas and nothing I've thought of yet has worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little trick, it works for all sorts of situations including yours. But also for trailing comma's for example.

### Concept

Instead of printing your text directly, store it in an array like so:

```
$information_to_print = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'];
$cols = [];

foreach ($information_to_print as $col) {
    $cols[] = 'This is: ' . $col;
}
```

Now all you have to do is implode the array, using closing and opening tags as glue, and wrap in corresponding elements.

```
echo '<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td>', $cols) . '</td></tr>;
```

### Implementation

In your particular case it would look something like this

```
<?php
$entriesConverted = [
    ['column_size' => 1,   'content' => 'Item 1', 'text_align' => 'Center'],
    ['column_size' => 0.5, 'content' => 'Item 2', 'text_align' => 'Center'],
    ['column_size' => 0.75, 'content' => 'Item 3', 'text_align' => 'Center'],
];

// Set the sum to 0 to keep things clean and simple
$sum = 0;
$blocks = [];
$block_i = 0;

// Echo the starting div
echo '<div class="content-block homepage-block row">', PHP_EOL;

// Loop through the new columns
foreach($entriesConverted as $newEntry){
    for ($i=$newEntry['column_size']; $i <= 1; $i++) {
        $sum += $i;
        $newEntry['column_size'] = str_replace([0.25, 0.33, 0.5, 0.67, 0.75, 1], ['col-md-3', 'col-md-4', 'col-md-6', 'col-md-8', 'col-md-9', 'col-md-12'], $newEntry['column_size']);
        $newEntry['text_align'] = str_replace(['Left', 'Center', 'Right', 'Justified'], ['text-left', 'text-center', 'text-right', 'text-justify'], $newEntry['text_align']);
        if (!isset($blocks[$block_i])) { $blocks[] = ''; }
        $blocks[$block_i] .= '<div class="' . $newEntry['column_size'] . ' ' . 
                             $newEntry['text_align'] . '">' . $newEntry['content'] .
                             '</div>';
    }
    if($sum == 1){
        $sum = 0;
        ++$block_i;
    }
}

echo implode("\n</div>\n<div class=\"content-block homepage-block row\">\n", $blocks);


// Echo closing div
echo PHP_EOL, '</div>';
```

See a working version here: http://ideone.com/28uXCT
*Note: I added some newlines to keep the output readable*

**warning:** Be aware of a bug in your code. As you can see in the output of ideone, the total column span of the second row exceeds 12.

Comment: Is there a chance you could explain this idea with my code? I'm using Expression Engine to build an array of entries in a grid. So I have to layout my array like that

Comment: Every array element/object needs to loop inside a row until the sum of 1 is reached, then create a new row and carry on

Comment: I've split the post in the concept of the answer (which you might find useful in other situations as well) and a concrete implementation for your case.

Comment: Thank you Maarten, I'll take a look now :)

Comment: This doesn't work. It puts every array object into it's own row. As I've said, it needs to loop through until 1 is achieved. Currently the `0.5` columns are in their own row which is wrong.

Comment: Basic flow would be this: Open .row div > loop through entries adding the column size up > if the size equals 1 close the row and start a new one > repeat until done > don't show an empty div at the end.

Comment: I see I was a little quick with my implementation. I'll be able to give you a working version later on. The concept should work for you though. Just need to re-implement the sum logic while building the array.

Comment: Thanks Maarten. Seems like a good idea, just not quite spot on at the minute :)

Comment: There it is! Also note the warning I added.

Comment: I'll take a look now :) The warning is fine, ill explain that to the client

Comment: I still get the additional empty div

Comment: Did you actually test this using my examples? Using your code (which does not equal a row of 1) it works. But when you switch 0.75 for 0.5 (which makes 1) it breaks. So, this solution is exactly the same problem as my initial issue

Comment: Hehe, whups. Sleepy me I guess. Fixed it.

Comment: Haha okay, let me check :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be easier if the row elements are inside the loop rather than outside. For example here's a quick pseudocode:

```
array items

sum = 0

loop through items

    open row

    print output for this item

    increment sum

    if sum is 1

        set sum 0

        close row

        if this is not the last item in the array

            open next row
```

Comment: *"if this is not the last item in the array"* would you use something like `end()` ?

Comment: If it's not the last item in the array then just print out the opening row tag again, no need to do any more php in that case as you'll be moving onto the next item

Comment: What would be the best way to check if it's the last item in the array?

Comment: Ah ok, so when you loop through the items, use   foreach items as i, item     then to check if its the last do something like       if( $i <= count($items) )